# I want to hide <i> tag whose data-original-title="Close" after page loads but it is visible in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page which opens in Modal window and I want to hide `<i>` tag whose `data-original-title="Close"` after page loads with the following code but it doesn't work: I am using SAAS system where there is an option to open a page in MODAL window.

```
function startUp() {    
  $("i[data-original-title='Close']").hide();
}    

<body onload="startUp(); return true;">    
</body>
```

I tried `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded'`... as well

Comment: Your code is fine and works in a snippet. The issue is likely that modal windows don't have a separate BODY tag (they shouldn't anyways) - You will need to invoke your code after the modal has been loaded in

Comment: I have added a pic and highlighted <i> which I want to hide.

Comment: what does the code look like that launches your modal? Can you add that to your question?

Comment: I am using SAAS system where there is an option to open a page in MODAL.

Comment: You could try putting your code in a `setTimeout(function () { ... }, 200)` call (varying the 200 up and down until it works). Of course, it would be better if the SAAS system provided an event handler you could hook into.

Comment: I tried setTimeout but it doesn't  work.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your modal DOM (In Developer tools (F12)).

Answer (score 2):

Given your use case and the JS code being supplied by a third party, I would recommend just using a CSS rule in your `styles.css` (or whatever file name) file.

```
.sswindow-backdrop i[data-original-title=Close] {
   display:none !important;
}
```

Comment: doesn't work in my case.

Comment: @KarimAli try `i[data-original-title=Close]` without parent selector.

Answer (score 0):

Your can access the `data-*` attribute using JQuery by using the `data()` method.

Have a look at the [JQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/data/) on this. They have plenty of examples.

**EDIT**

> I want to hide tag whose data-original-title="Close" after page loads

You can use the document `readystatechange` [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readystatechange_event) to hide the element that contain "Close" in the data attribute.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  $('#container div').each(function() {
    if ($(this).data('original-title') == 'Close') {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div data-original-title="Close" id="div1">Close</div>
  <div data-original-title="Close" id="div2">Close</div>
  <div data-original-title="Keep Open" id="div3">Keep Open</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, you can access data-atrributes like that in jquery, but there's nothing wrong with the standard javascript method the OP is using. This answer does not address the problem

Comment: You also talk about the `readystatechange` event, but then use `window`'s `load` event...

Comment: @HereticMonkey, that’s correct. I referenced the readystatechange along with the link so that Karim Ali can read more about it. They will need to decide if using the document readystate or the window load event will be best suitable

Comment: The `data` method does not affect data attributes, as mentioned in the documentation https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: @NiceBooks yes....but I am not trying to add/alter the data attributes - just reading them. KarimAli does not mention that they want to change any data-attributes.

Comment: @Voorie Sorry, but I'm unable to undo the downvote. It says that my vote is locked until answer edit.

Comment: @NiceBooks no problem at all, was just a misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

try

```js
function startUp() {    
  $("i[data-original-title='Close']").attr("style", "display:none!important");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Attribute selectors use double quotes (") & not single quotes (').
jQuery does not throw any error, if the element does not exist in the DOM.
So better use Vanilla js to debug:

```
 var closeBtn = document.querySelector('i[data-original-title="Close"]');
 closeBtn.style.display = 'none';
```

You have not provided enough code or DOM screenshot in your question, but I strongly suspect you the modal's content is in an `iframe`, in which case it is in a separate DOM.

```
 var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
 iframe.addEventListener('load', (evt)=> {
     // hide close button here.
 });
```